# Can a message be encrypted with a Monero address and then decrypted by the address's owner?

Tags: encrypted-messaging

Some Bitcoin wallets have this functionality: they let you encrypt an arbitrary text with a Bitcoin address such that only the owner of the address can read the text.

The Monero wallet software allows you to [*sign a message*](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-does-one-prove-ownership-of-a-monero-address) with your own *private keys*, but I'm asking about *encrypting* with someone else's [public] *address*. (I'm not asking about [embedding messages in transactions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/is-it-possible-to-embed-message-for-recipient-in-transaction).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically possible (that is what the short payment ids are), but I don't think there's any existing command for this at the moment.